# How do I keep the image inside or within the modal body as I rotate it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image: Blockquote]

This is the code within my css file.

```
#children {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    object-fit: contain;
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

My screenshot below

This is the code snippet - (please see below)

```
 <div className="modal" id="modal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="modalLabel">{title}</h5>
              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body" style={{transform: `rotate(${this.props.rotation}deg)`}} id="children">
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some more of your code, ideally as an [mcve] inside of a snippet?  This is not really enough to easily understand the specific issue you are facing.

Comment: I have attached the css snippet and screenshot above. I hope this helps.

Comment: The screenshot is helpful, thank you.  However, there is no information regarding the markup, nor the CSS for the modal itself.  Without this context, there's simply too much guesswork for the community to provide you with any helpful, meaningful guidance.

Comment: maybe just didnt understand it properly, but what if you set  modal height to auto, having min-height to be height with no image ?

Comment: Keep in mind `transform`'s are purely visual - the dimensions of the image in relation to the DOM are as they were prior to the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I tried setting the modal height to auto. Don't think it worked for me. How do I set the min height to height with no image?